# How does one find values of constants in a value function?

Tags: macroeconomics, bellman-equations, recursive-macroeconomics

Problem:

suppose I have the following maximization problem:
\begin{align}
&\max_{(c_t)_{t \geq 0}}E_0\left[\sum^{\infty}_{t=0}\beta^{t}\ln c_t\right]\\[2mm]
\text{s.t.} \quad & k_{t+1}=A^{1-\alpha}_tk^{\alpha}_t - c_t\\[2mm]
& c_t \in [0,A^{1-\alpha}_tk^{\alpha}_t]
\end{align}
with $\beta \in (0,1)$ and $\alpha\in (0,1)$.
I know that I am supposed to “guess” the value function and I have this $V(A_t,k_t)=X+Y \ln(A_t)+Z \ln(k_t)$.

Derive the values of the constants.

This value function comes from bellman equation that is not given.

We are given this other bit:

$\ln A_{t+1}=\rho \ln A_t +\epsilon _{t+1}$ $\rho \in (0,1)$

My question: should I start off this problem by setting up a Lagrangian function and then calculating the values or no?

Comment: You should start by writing down the proper problem.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention. I have made the necessary edits.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://people.brandeis.edu/~ghall/econ182/_build/html/stochastic_dynamic_programming.html

Comment: Thank you for the helpful link. I still need to derive the values of the constants in my value function, but this greatly helped me.